# Updated to Ionic 3 from Ionic 2, now unable to build due to "Unexpected token {" error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

After going through the upgrade steps defined in the Ionic Blog ([detailed here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/guide-how-to-update-to-ionic-3-x/87516)), I am not unable to build my Ionic project due to a very non-detailed error message about invalid syntax somewhere.  Here is the full error:

```
[14:16:31]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[14:16:31]  SyntaxError: Unexpected token { 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\build-optimizer\webpack-loader.js:12:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
```

I've made attempts to debug through this using the details above, but haven't gotten anywhere at all.  Before getting this error, I haven't made any changes other than what was detailed above (perhaps I missed something?).  Any thoughts?

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "com.myapp.test",
    "author": "",
    "homepage": "",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
        "rxjs": "5.4.3",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "description": "",
    "cordovaPlugins": [],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [],
    "-vs-binding": {
        "BeforeBuild": [
            "ionic:build"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js",
        "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
    }
}
```

**output from `ionic info`**

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Node : v6.10.3
    npm  : 4.6.1
    OS   : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: Can you show the `ionic info` and `package.json`?

Comment: added package.json, what ionic info are you looking for?

Comment: Just type it in your `cmd` and show the output? `> ionic info`

Comment: added ionic info

Comment: @c0r3yz I have the same problem however your approved answer doesn't help. Please provide your solution which mentioned in your comments.

Comment: Basically, using the advice from @Sampath , I went and got VS Code and went through ensuring all the appropriate tools were setup to build from there. Going down that path got me to the point where I was getting more meaningful errors from the Cordova CLI that lead me to my syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `Ionic info`, you don't have `Android SDK Tools`. So you need to install it.

I'm using `Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5`.

And you need to install `cordova` too.

This is my details:

> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
> ```

See how to [**setup Ionic 3 environment**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 with VS Tools for Apache Cordova and was building just fine with my current configuration, is this something that changed for Ionic 3?

Comment: cordova - 6.3.1 and cordova-android 5.2.1

Comment: Why it doesn't show when you used `ionic info`? You can read more about `Ionic 3` environment here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/clarify-ionic-3-build-process/90031/5

Comment: I have added another link too.

Comment: Your information got me on the right path.  There were command changes from Ionic 2 to Ionic 3.  Until Visual Studios updates their tools, I will need to just execute the steps manually using the documentation provided.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: And I highly recommend using `VS code` for frontend development.